# Is there anyway to inject key event to other apps without root privilege?

Tags: android

I try to find a way to inject keyEvent into other apps. However, the solutions usually involved with root privilege or get system signature.

Is there anyway to inject the input event into other apps without root the device? I think, the platform key is usually hold by the device provider who create the ROM. So it is not a valid way either.

I knew it can be down, for example the "Button savior non root".

Does anyone have any experience in this?

Comment: Which key events to you want to use? There might be intents for ie home button etc. Not sure if that's how button savior non root works or not.

Comment: @David Olsson I would like to simulate the home button, volume button and D-pad buttons.

Comment: Pretty sure you can simulate the home button and volume buttons using intents which I really think it's how the non root does it, regular keys is probably impossible or really hard. Maybe if you simulate a controller (such as an usb gamepad). Just loose ideas.

Comment: https://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/19/android-simulate-key-strokes/ Check here, has a good example.